# How to post new data with traverson to a Spring Data Rest Service?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I can't find any example online on how to post a new entity with traverson to a Spring Data Rest Service. Does anybody has a helping link?

I really get stuck while trying to send this data:

```
{           
   billingService: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/billingServices/1",
   invoicingPartyId: "xyz",
   mandator: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mandators/1"
}
```

with this JavaScript Code:

```
this.newBillingServiceClient = function(billingServiceClient) {
        var api = traverson
            .from(BasePath)
            .jsonHal()
            .withRequestOptions({
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            });
        return api.follow('billingServiceClients')
            .post(billingServiceClient).result.then(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc);
            }, function(err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

Here is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "BILLING_SERVICE_ID", "MANDATOR_ID" }) })
@Data
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class BillingServiceClient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private Mandator mandator;

    @OneToOne(optional = false)
    private BillingService billingService;

    @NotEmpty
    private String invoicingPartyId;

    @CreatedBy
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createdDate;

    @LastModifiedBy
    private String modifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date lastModifiedDate;

}
```

and my repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceDescription = @Description("Rechnungsservicemandant"))
public interface BillingServiceClientRepository extends CrudRepository<BillingServiceClient, Long> {

}
```

Traverson is only sending GET requests while following the links, but no post to send the data.

Here is the response to the BasePath which may be helpful?!

```
{
  "_links": {
    "billingServices": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/billingServices"
    },
    "mandators": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/mandators"
    },
    "billingServiceClients": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/billingServiceClients"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

A simple link to a useful online resource would be sufficient... (or any idea on how to solve my problem with traverson, of course I could use simple $http or $resource but I would like to use traverson).

Btw. I am using:
https://github.com/basti1302/traverson-angular (3.1.1) and 
https://github.com/basti1302/traverson-hal (4.1.1) and
Spring Boot 1.4.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.

Thank you,
Christian

P.S.: Why is there no traverson tag? Is no one using it???

Comment: It works with traverson if I post my data directly to the given url:
`traverson.from(BasePath + '/billingServiceClients')    .withRequestOptions({
     headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     }
    }).post(billingServiceClient)...`
But is this the right way?